# How can I get a set of raw samples from an audio file in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, audio

In particular, I'd like to know how to get a set of audio samples that are compatible with the XNA's Sound API classes, such as the `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` class.

I've used the `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` class for synthesizer work in XNA [before](http://www.david-gouveia.com/creating-a-basic-synth-in-xna-part-iii/). But now instead of synthesizing my sounds, I'd like to read audio samples directly out of audio files - basically I want to do my own mixing and sequencing of samples into a single `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` object. I've had subtle timing problems when trying to do sequencing on XNA before using regular timers and `Play()` calls, so I need more control.

Clearly, XNA already knows how to load sounds, for instance, using the content pipeline and the `SoundEffect` class. Is the underlying format used by the `SoundEffect` class the same as the one used by the `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` class - signed 16 bit interleaved PCM?

In short, how do I reach the point where I can play an audio file using the `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827591.aspx). This shows you how to read and play a WAV file with DSEI (with streaming, too).

The same technique can be used for audio in other formats, but you will have to bring your own converter. Google may be able to help if you need to support other formats.

XNA's `SoundEffect` can use PCM that are (I think) in the same format as DSEI. But it can also accept compressed sound effects in some Microsoft proprietary format. However there does not appear to be any way to access its PCM data directly.

Comment: I wonder why I didn't notice there was an MSDN article on this already :) That's exactly what I needed, and for my purposes it's fine to support only wave files.

Comment: I was half-way through replicating the contents of the tutorial in my answer before I stumbled upon it ;)